# Which grammatical situations depend on the literal gender of a speaker?

Tags: род

Recently, a friend accused me of misgendering myself by using "feminine" verb endings. I am aware of many situations where there are verb endings for the grammatical gender of the noun, but when should I worry about inflecting words with my literal gender? I seem to recall a situation where this happens, but I can't find the explanation for it at the moment.

Comment: Speaking about any person (no matter yourself or somebody else) you should always use their  real gender.

Comment: But which parts of speech will that affect? Obviously I want to use the right pronoun, but I believe my friend was complaining about declension

Comment: Every part that can be gender specific, verbs and adjectives in the first place.

Comment: All of them singular: verbs in past tense, adjectives and participles, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost anything that can serve as an adjective: adjectives proper, participles, ordinal numerals, possessive pronouns etc.:

> Я красивый (m.) / я красивая (f.)
>
> Я богат (m.) / я богата (f.)
>
> Я обиженный (m.) / я обиженная (f.)
>
> Я первый (m.) / я первая (f.)
>
> Я сам (m.) / я сама (m.)

Verbs in past single (etymologically they are participles too):

> Я сделал (m.) / я сделала (f.)

Some collective numerals:

> Мы оба (m.) / мы обе (f.)
>
> Двое из нас (m.) / две из нас (f.)

Several nouns:

> Я дурак (m.) / я дура (f.)
>
> Я певец (m.) / я певица (f.)

Several adverbs:

> Я женат (m.) / я замужем (f.)
>
> Я холост (m.) / я не замужем (f.)

Comment: Are you referring to grammatical gender or the literal gender of the speaker? I understand declension by grammatical gender, what I am curious about is the situations where the speaker's literal gender would override that.

Comment: @baordog What do you mean by "override"? Grammtical gender must always match speaker's gender.

Comment: @baordog: sentences marked "m." are those a Russian speaking male would have said. Grammatical gender in such sentences always agrees with the sex the speaker identifies themselves with.

Comment: @baordog: to clarify a little bit: adjectives and past verbs in Russian do not have a gender on their own, they agree for gender with the noun they modify. Most nominals have a fixed grammatical gender in Russian, however, personal pronouns and some so called "common gender" words assume the biological gender of the person they define.

Comment: @baordog: *Ложка* is always feminine in Russian, *стол* is always masculine, so it's always *красивая ложка* and *красивый стол* no matter what. However, words like *я*, *ты*, *убийца*, *жадина* are masculine or feminine depending on whether it is a man or a woman they define, so a man would be *хладнокровный убийца* while a woman would be *хладнокровная убийца*.

Comment: женат и холост are adjectives.

Comment: Always make sure to use **беременный** in the correct gender! ;-)